# How can I create API end point in Next.js with query string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, query-string

I need to create the following API end point using Next.js:

`/api/products/[name]?keyword=${anykeyword}`.

I know I need to create it inside pages/api/products/[name] directory in index.js. But how can I access `keyword`.

`req.query` only contains `name`.

following is my code:

```
import { connectToDatabase } from "../../../../util/mongodb";
import validate from "../../../../validation/product";
//capitalize first letter only to avoid errors
import capitalize from "lodash.capitalize";

export default async function productsHandler(req, res) {
const {
  query: { name, keyword }, // here i cannot access keyword//
  method,
} = req,
Name = capitalize(name),
{ db } = await connectToDatabase(),
searchCriteria = keyword ? keyword : "price";

switch (method) {
case "GET":
  // @route GET api/products/[name]
  // @desc get products of [name] from data base
  // @access public
  {
    const products = await db
      .collection("products")
      .find({ category: Name })
      .sort({ [searchCriteria]: 1 })
      .toArray();

    if (!products.length)
      return res.status(404).json({ error: "no such category" });

    res.status(200).json(products);
  }

  break;
```

Comment: `req.query` should return the `keyword` bit according to https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/15472#issuecomment-678357324. Can you share your code?

Comment: i just did Dominik

Comment: How are you making the request to the API route?

Comment: I think this is what you need https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/47072#discussioncomment-5291376

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It probably has to do with how the request is being sent to the server side from the client. You probably need to revise that. I just tried out the example using Postman, and it correctly parsed the parameters:

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

export default async (request: NextApiRequest, response: NextApiResponse) => {
  const {
    query: { name, keyword },
    method,
  } = request;
  console.log(name, keyword, method);

  // do nothing fancy and simply return a string concatenation
  return response.status(200).json({ query: name + " " + keyword });
};
```

Postman:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to default a query parameter to something?

Answer (score 10):

To get the search parameters you can simply use `req.nextUrl.serachParams.get("keyword")`

```js
async function GET(req:NextRequest){
 console.log(req.nextUrl.searchParams.get("keyword"))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me:

```js
export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  const qs = getQSParamFromURL("qs", req.url);
  return new Response(
    JSON.stringify({
      data: {
        hello: qs,
      },
    }),
    {
      status: 200,
      headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "cache-control": "public, s-maxage=1800, stale-while-revalidate=600",
      },
    }
  );
}

export function getQSParamFromURL(
  key: string,
  url: string | undefined
): string | null {
  if (!url) return "";
  const search = new URL(url).search;
  const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(search);
  return urlParams.get(key);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Hello everything is fine? Well in next 13 we have some solutions to get the URL parameters, considering that your folder structure is:

- _api
- __ user (folder)
- ___ [id] (folder)
- ____ route.js

Using the code example:

```js
export async function GET(req, res) {
    
    const id = req.url.split("user/")[1];
    
    return NextResponse.json({ id }, { status: 200 });
}
```

We can do the following:

URL Example: /api/user/12

And we capture it with `req.url.split("company/")[1]`

Comment: The second param is not `res`, but `context`. https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route#context-optional

Comment: Is a example of the code